# Google Foobar - "Distract the Trainers"

Tags: java, array

### QUESTION:

You will set up simultaneous thumb wrestling matches. In each match, two trainers will pair off to thumb wrestle. The trainer with fewer bananas will bet all their bananas, and the other trainer will match the bet. The winner will receive all of the bet bananas. You don't pair off trainers with the same number of bananas (you will see why, shortly). You know enough trainer psychology to know that the one who has more bananas always gets over-confident and loses. Once a match begins, the pair of trainers will continue to thumb wrestle and exchange bananas, until both of them have the same number of bananas. Once that happens, both of them will lose interest and go back to supervising the bunny workers, and you don't want THAT to happen!

For example, if the two trainers that were paired started with 3 and 5 bananas, after the first round of thumb wrestling they will have 6 and 2 (the one with 3 bananas wins and gets 3 bananas from the loser). After the second round, they will have 4 and 4 (the one with 6 bananas loses 2 bananas). At that point they stop and get back to training bunnies.

How is all this useful to distract the bunny trainers? Notice that if the trainers had started with 1 and 4 bananas, then they keep thumb wrestling! 1, 4 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 4 and so on.

Now your plan is clear. You must pair up the trainers in such a way that the maximum number of trainers go into an infinite thumb wrestling loop!

Write a function solution(banana_list) which, given a list of positive integers depicting the amount of bananas the each trainer starts with, returns the fewest possible number of bunny trainers that will be left to watch the workers. Element i of the list will be the number of bananas that trainer i (counting from 0) starts with.

The number of trainers will be at least 1 and not more than 100, and the number of bananas each trainer starts with will be a positive integer no more than 1073741823 (i.e. 2^30 -1). Some of them stockpile a LOT of bananas.

-- Java cases --

Input:
solution.solution(1,1)

Output:
2

Input:
Solution.solution([1, 7, 3, 21, 13, 19])

Output:
0

### My approach:

Check the GCD of the pair. For repeating loops the GCD never changes. For terminating sequences the GCD doubles at each step. However there is a third kind of loop to consider. Some have a lead in sequence than doesn’t repeat but eventually turns into a looping sequence. For these the GCD will increase each step for the non repeating lead in part of the sequence, then will become static for the repeating section. So just testing the first and second step of a sequence will not be enough.

We can take this a step further however. If any of the GCDs divide the sum of the pair into a power of 2 then the loop is terminating.

### MY CODE:

```
public class Solution {
    public static int gcd(int a, int b)
    {
        // Everything divides 0
        if (a == 0)
          return b;
        if (b == 0)
          return a;
      
        // base case
        if (a == b)
            return a;
      
        // a is greater
        if (a > b)
            return gcd(a-b, b);
        return gcd(a, b-a);
    }
    
    static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int n)
    {
        if(n==0)
        return false;
     
    return (int)(Math.ceil((Math.log(n) / Math.log(2)))) == (int)(Math.floor(((Math.log(n) / Math.log(2)))));
    }
    public static int countpairs(int[] b) {
        int c=0;
        for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++)
                c++;
        }
        return c;
    }
    public static int solution(int[] banana_list) {
        int[] b=banana_list;
        int count=countpairs(b);
        for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++) {
                if(i==j) {}
                else {
                    int s=(b[i]+b[j])/gcd(b[i],b[j]);
                    if(isPowerOfTwo(s)==true)
                        count--;
                }
            }
        }
        if(count>b.length)
            return 0;
        
        return count;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[]= {1,1};
        System.out.println("Minimum trainers: "+solution(a));
    }
}
```

This code passes 2/5 Test cases.
It fails in cases where there are odd number of trainers.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We only review code that is working as expected, there are other sites that will help you debug your code. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: (I found *no* rendition of the problem tackled explicitly specifying what to output.)

Answer (score 1):

#### Recursion is good only if you know its depth

If you have a tree with maximum depth of 100 or so - recursion is normal to traverse it. But here you can get a million steps of recursion for a stupid example of gcd(1,1000000). Change it to the loop.

#### GCD can be calculated faster if you change subtraction with modulo

Because (a-b)%b === (a%b)%b, gcd persists.

#### Power of two can be checked with bitwise logic

You can try shifting right until the number is odd and check if it's 1, that's faster than your solution; but there's also a trick: `x&(x-1)==0` only for powers of 2.

#### `countpairs` is just a square of length

You don't need to loop over an array to count its elements

#### Algorithm

To find out if the numbers are tied, you don't need GCD at all:
If both numbers are equal - they are tied.
If one is even, other odd - the will be no tie.
If both are odd - make them fight (i.e. recalculate them by the fight rules) and repeat.
If both are even - divide them by two and repeat. This will be much faster than your GCD.

Also your pairing algorithm is flawed, check {1,1,1,2} - it should return 2, but it gives 0.

Comment: I agree with the first three points. However, when you talk about the Algorithm, you mention that "If both numbers are even - divide them by two. If one is even, other odd - the will be no termination." Won't even numbers always be even when divided by 2? That is the whole concept of odd and even! I might be understanding this wrongly, I'm sorry if I am. Can you please clarify?

Comment: My algorithm is pretty basic and it works most times. However, I've noticed that I have made a mistake in the counting part of the algorithm. i.e, counting, the number of trainers who cannot make an infinite loop. This is the part I cant figure out...

Comment: Nevermind the "algorithm" part, I'll edit the answer and remove it when I'll have time.

Comment: `you don't need GCD` You may have rediscovered [Binary GCD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm).